# How to use Vista's SuperFetch with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-vista

Vista's SuperFetch works well with applications installed, but it does not seem to do so with Eclipse, which is just copied in a directory.

Does anyone know how to correct this ? Or is it simply not possible ?

[I hope this one will not be closed as "not programming related", since I need Eclipse on my machine for programming ;-) ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since **[SuperFetch](http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2007/03/29/windows-vista-superfetch-readyboost.aspx)** analyzes the application that you launch, it should pick up on the eclipse.exe and - more importantly - the underlying javaw.exe process which is created by eclipse.exe

So even if eclipsed in not installed per say, I would argue SuperFetch should at least pick up on the java process usage.

Do you see javaw in your [%SystemRoot%\Prefetch directory](http://readerszone.com/operating-system/windows/windows-vista-windows-operating-system/superfetch-performance-enhancing-features-in-windows-vista.html) (which should not be empty [nor emptied](http://www.edbott.com/weblog/archives/000024.html)) ?

Comment: I don't see a javaw.exe in "%SystemRoot%\Prefetch"
But an eclipse.exe and a java.exe are there.
Do you think this is suitable ?

Comment: yes, that is a clear sign that superFetch has detected those applications. So it should mean superFetch works also for eclipse

Comment: THANX ! the question is answered now. greetings